# Selective IPrincipal Injection via StructureMap with SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, signalr, iprincipal

StructureMap is configured to inject `HttpContext.Current.User` when an `IPrincipal` is requested for any ASP.NET MVC web request, like so:

```
For<IPrincipal>().Use(x => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

But when my SignalR hub asks for a service that depends on an `IPrincipal`, injection fails because `HttpContext.Current` is null. Instead, SignalR already has a `HubCallerContext` property that exposes the current `IPrincipal` via `Context.User`.

How do I configure StructureMap to always inject a valid `IPrincipal` into the services my SignalR hub relies on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
For<IPrincipal>().Use(x => Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the current `HubCallerContext` from outside of the hub? AFAIK, there is no static, global `HubCallerContext.Current` like there is for HttpContext.

Comment: Ahh okay.. And you can't use the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentPrincipal`?

Comment: Going to try `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` (for non-static context).